# Onclick is not working in asp:Button?

Tags: asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#LogStatusLable').click(function () {
                $('#LoginPanel').slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $('#LoginPanel').hide();

        });
    </script>

<div id="LoginPanel">
  <br />
  <div class="grid_6">
  <br />
  <a>New User Registration</a>
  </div>
  <table class="grid_6">
      <tr>
      <td>Email-ID</td>
      <td>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UsernameTextBox" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordTextBox" TextMode="Password" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="LoginValidation" Text=""></asp:Label>  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
     <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Text="Login" 
                                      CssClass="buttoncss" onclick="Login_Click" />
      <br /> <br />
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>

</div>

protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UsernameTextBox != null && PasswordTextBox.Text != null)
        {
            if (_user.GetandSetUserDetails(UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                LoginValidation.Text = "Invalid username or password";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LoginValidation.Text = "Enter the Username and Password";
        }
    }
```

I used the jquery to slideup and slidedown the div tag. Its working correctly but the inside of the div tag i used the asp:button its not functioning well. onclick property is dosent work. Please help me to find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any [Login-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)? What happens in page_load? Is the `Login_Click` part of codebehind or on aspx(maybe you've forgotten to add `<script runat="server">`)?

Answer (score 0):

remove any duplicate form tag in page.